# Is java.lang.reflect.Field instance uniq in single class loader?

Tags: java, synchronization, classloader

I have some java codes synchronized in a Field object. It looks like:

```
Field f = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredField("field1");
synchronized(f) {
  ....
}
```

Can java ensure that everytime I get a Field object by reflection, it's alway the same instance? So I can synchronize code block on it.
I know it's ok for Class, but not sure about Field.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple example shows that it is not the same instance (it prints false). Why would you want to synchronized on a `Field` object anyway? I suppose you realise that it is not equivalent to locking on the underlying variable.

You should explain *why* you want to do that, as there certainly is a better option.

```
class Test {

    int i;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class c = Test.class;
        Field f1 = c.getDeclaredField("i");
        Field f2 = c.getDeclaredField("i");
        System.out.println(f1 == f2); //prints false
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to implement auto-increment column in database. So all create operation in regards to that field(column) should be synchronized.

Comment: @WilliamBao Then you should probably ask that question. Depending on the database, there might be a way to have it done automatically for you. If not, a `Map<String, AtomicInteger>` for example, where the key is the column and the value the "auto-increment" part might work.